# Multiple ostream on a file produces different order of output

Tags: c++, fstream, ostream

Why does multiple ostream on a file being written to produce a different order of output? For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void writeTo(string filename){
    ostream o;
    o.open(filename, ios::app);
    o << "Second\n";
    o.close();
}

int main(){
    ostream o;
    o.open("foo.txt", ios::app);
    o << "First\n";
    writeTo("foo.txt");
    o.close();
    return 0;
}
```

The output file is

```
Second
First
```

Why is this the case?  Shouldn't it be First then Second?

I know I can achieve this behavior by having one stream and passing it by reference as such, but I'm confused what causes this behavior of multiple streams on the same file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void writeTo(ostream& o){
    o << "Second\n";
}

int main(){
    ostream o;
    o.open("foo.txt", ios::app);
    o << "First\n";
    writeTo(o);
    o.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `ostream` inside the function is destroyed before the one in `main()`, so it flushes its buffer first.

Comment: @cantordust Interesting, can you please cite that?

Comment: You are calling `close()` explicitly, so technically the buffer is flushed before the stream is destroyed, but this is irrelevant because the destructor will call `close()` anyway. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/close): `[...] first calls overflow(Traits::eof()) to write all pending output to the file [...]`. You should get `First` followed by `Second` if you call `o.close()` **before** calling `writeTo("foo.txt");` in `main()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the order you `.close()` your ostreams.

First you are opening the file in append mode, and buffering 'First,' but this doesn't actually reach the file yet.

```
ostream o;
o.open("foo.txt", ios::app);
o << "First\n";
```

Then, you open the file again, and buffer 'Second,' closing the file, and actually putting the buffer into the file.

```
ostream o;
o.open(filename, ios::app);
o << "Second\n";
o.close();
```

Finally, you do `o.close();` in your main function, outputting the first ostream, which contained 'First', into the file. Since it was opened in `ios::app` (append mode), that text goes to the end of the file, creating what you saw:

```
Second
First
```

More reading:

File opening modes: http://www.dummies.com/programming/cpp/open-modes-in-c/

How `ostream::close()` works: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/close/

To avoid this in the future, typically you should close the file before you open it again, or flush the file after you wrote it the first time before you write it again, like seen here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/flush/

`ostream::flush()` forces the buffer to be moved into the file.